# Disable default installation of LXD with Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lxd

Since Ubuntu 16.04 LXD has become a dependency in the ubuntu-server meta package. Hence both upgrade and new installation will install LXD.

This is a very annoying behavior. Is there anyway to disable this behavior? Not every production machine needs the container service to be started.

Answer (score 9):

`lxd` is recommended by `ubuntu-server`

```
root@c7:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

root@c7:~# apt-cache depends ubuntu-server|grep lxd
  Recommends: lxd

root@c7:~# apt-cache depends ubuntu-server|grep Recommends
  Recommends: lxd
  Recommends: snapd
```

You can use

```
apt install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-server
```

to avoid installing `lxd` and `snapd` or

```
apt remove --purge lxd snapd
```

to remove these without removing ubuntu-server

```
root@c7:~# apt remove --purge lxd snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  lxd* snapd*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 37.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 25405 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing lxd (2.0.0-0ubuntu4) ...
Warning: Stopping lxd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  lxd.socket
Purging configuration files for lxd (2.0.0-0ubuntu4) ...
Failed to stop lxd.service: Unit lxd.service not loaded.
dpkg: warning: while removing lxd, directory '/var/lib/lxd' not empty so not removed
Removing snapd (2.0.3) ...
Purging configuration files for snapd (2.0.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you just want to disable related services, not to uninstall them. Since they are just another services, we can disable them using systemctl

```
sudo systemctl disable lxd
sudo systemctl disable snapd
```

If someday you want to start them.

```
sudo systemctl start lxd
sudo systemctl start snapd
```

Simple as is.